# PHP no div style

Tags: php, html, css

I made a PHP Script, but my php have no background color, the div is `#LoginBalk` now is see only this

[image]

Looks good but no background...

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Je bent ingelogd!</title>
    <style>
      #LoginBalk {
        background: red;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="LoginBalk">
      <?php

            session_start();
            include 'connect.php'; // je connectie erin zetten
            if (!isset($_SESSION['login'])) { // controleren of de session login niet      bestaan
              echo "<div style=float:left; width:200px>";
              echo "<img src=Default.png>";
              echo "</div>";
              echo "<div style=float:left; width:200px>";
              echo "<br> <br>Welkom <b>Gast</B><br>";
              echo 'Je bent niet ingelogd<Br>';
              echo '<a href="login.php">Login</a>';
              echo "</div>";
            } else {
              echo "<div style=float:left; width:200px>";
              echo "<img src=https://www.habbo.nl/habbo-imaging/avatarimage?user=" .      $_SESSION['naam'] . " onError=this.src='Default.png' >";
              echo "</div>";
              echo "<div style=float:left; width:200px>";
              echo "<br> <br>Welkom <B>" . $_SESSION['naam'] . "</b></br>";
              echo "Je bent ingelogd <br>";
              echo '<a href="uit.php">Uitloggen</a>';
              echo "</div>";
            }
        ?>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Don't add PHP code, use generated HTML from browser and add here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should help:

```
<style>
#LoginBalk {
  background: red;
  overflow: hidden;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Omg, It helps. Thank you!!

Comment: @Tomas Turkowski, Indra accepted another solution there I can't find correct solution. I can't understand what he was trying to say and what he accepted.

Answer (score 1):

add this style

```
<style>
 #LoginBalk {
     background: red;
     display: inline-block;
  }
```

Comment: Could you add some explanation also?

Answer (score 0):

Add `float: left;` on your style like,

```
#LoginBalk {
     background: red;
     float: left;
}
```

It will be working for your case

Also set `width` and `height` for the above style.

Answer (score 0):

And you use too much echo try like this :

```
if (!isset($_SESSION['login'])) {
echo '<div style=float:left; width:200px>
    <img src=Default.png>
    </div>
    <div style=float:left; width:200px>
    <br> <br>Welkom <b>Gast</B><br>
    Je bent niet ingelogd<Br>
    <a href="login.php">Login</a>
     </div>';
} else { 
echo '<div style=float:left; width:200px>
    <img src=https://www.habbo.nl/habbo-imaging/avatarimage?user=" .      $_SESSION['naam'] . " onError=this.src='Default.png' >
    </div>
    <div style=float:left; width:200px>";
    <br> <br>Welkom <B>" . $_SESSION['naam'] . "</b></br>";
    Je bent ingelogd <br>";
    <a href="uit.php">Uitloggen</a>
    </div>';
}
```

Comment: Ok, Thanks, I'm gonna do that